# Force dtSearch Engine to use a specific dtengine64.dll

Tags: c#, dtsearch

I am working on a custom ASP.NET using dtSearch Engine for custom indexing and searching. The web server is shared and have other ASP.NET application running that also use dtSearch Engine for different tasks. The issue is that the dtSearch Engine dtengine64.dll registered on the server is an older version which seems to have a bug. So I want to supply a new version of the dtengine64.dll for my own ASP.NET application. So per recommendation from dtSearch [support page](https://support.dtsearch.com/webhelp/dtSearchNetApi2/dtSearch__Engine__Server__SetEnginePath@String%5E.html).

I used `SetEnginePath` before I initialized a new IndexJob

```
Server.SetEnginePath(@"\\Path To\dtengine64.dll");
using (Server dtSearchServer = new Server())
{                
logger.LogInfo("dtSearch Major Version: {0}", dtSearchServer.MajorVersion);
logger.LogInfo("dtSearch Minor Version: {0}", dtSearchServer.MinorVersion);                
logger.LogInfo("dtSearch Build: {0}", dtSearchServer.Build);                
}
```

However, it won't pick up the dll I specify in `SetEnginePath`. Is there a way to force `SetEnginePath` to pick up the new path to DLL and use that within my application? It appears once the dtSearch Engine is loaded by any process on the server, it will stay in memory and can't be changed without completely shutting of all process using dtSearch.

Thanks,
Sean

I tried testing as Console application, changing different way to change the Engine Path and none of them worked.